# Windows 8 heap randomization

Tags: windows-8, heap-memory, 32bit-64bit, internals, aslr

Does the heap randomization algorithm (for allocating heap memory) in windows 8 works both for 32 and 64 bit processes? or only for 64 bit processes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Windows Vista and later (32/64 bit) have a heap randomization algorithm.

It seems that Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) for 32 bit Windows [may not be as robust as expected](http://www.symantec.com/avcenter/reference/Address_Space_Layout_Randomization.pdf) but Windows 8 32 bit ASLR has managed to [mitigate some weaknesses in low memory situations](http://recxltd.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/partial-technique-against-aslr-multiple.html).

ASLR is not enabled by default (e.g. [Heap randomization in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1232081/3235496) and [ASLR and Windows System DLLs for non-aware executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6396234/3235496)).

For further details, refer to [Black Hat USA 2012 - Windows 8 Heap Intervals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxlzK0CLFN0)