# Explain to me how Windows allocates process virtual memory

Tags: windows, process, virtual-memory, stack-memory

I have pretty complex question combined of multiple related questions. Let me give you the preamble.

I wrote a simple Win64 program in assembly language which prints "2 + 3 = 5" using `printf` and then "Hello World!" using `puts`:

```
format PE64
entry start

section '.text' code readable executable

  start:
        sub     rsp,8*5         ; reserve stack for API use and make stack dqword aligned

        mov edx, 3
        mov ecx, 2
        call print_sum

        lea     rcx,[_hw_message]
        call    [puts]

        mov     ecx,0
        call    [ExitProcess]

  print_sum:
        sub rsp, 20h
        mov r9d, ecx
        add r9d, edx
        mov r8d, edx
        mov edx, ecx
        lea ecx, [_format_message]
        call [printf]
        add rsp, 20h
        ret

section '.data' data readable writeable

  _hw_message db 'Hello World!',0
  _format_message db '%d + %d = %d',13,10,0

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

  dd 0,0,0,RVA kernel_name,RVA kernel_table
  dd 0,0,0,RVA msvcrt_name,RVA msvcrt_table

  kernel_table:
    ExitProcess dq RVA _ExitProcess
    dq 0
  msvcrt_table:
    printf dq RVA _printf
    puts dq RVA _puts
    dq 0

  kernel_name db 'KERNEL32.DLL',0
  msvcrt_name db 'msvcrt.dll',0

  _ExitProcess dw 0
    db 'ExitProcess',0
  _printf dw 0
    db 'printf',0
  _puts dw 0
    db 'puts',0
```

and built it with **fasm**. Resulting binary size is 2048 bytes.

I've opened it with **CFF Explorer** to see PE header values.
[image: PE64HELLO.EXE headers in CFF Explorer]

Image base is 0x400000, entry point is 0x1000, **.text** section virtual address is 0x1000 too, so, as far as I understand, it should start in virtual memory at offset 0x401000 and it is also its entry point.

Then I've opened it in debugger (I use **x64dbg**) to confirm my guess:
[image: PE64HELLO.EXE in x64dbg]
[image: Memory map of PE64HELLO.EXE in x64dbg]

Looks believable. Also note that stack is located at 0x8A000.

Fine, then I've tried the same with another program – **notepad.exe** from C:\Windows:
[image: notepad.exe in CFF Explorer and x64dbg]

Wait, what? 0x140000000 + 0x24050 = 0x140024050, not 0x7FF75FD04050. And I can't find in PE headers such big values starting with 7FF.

In addition, the stack is again located somewhere at the beginning of the process's memory map, but now its address is already much larger:
[image: Memory map of notepad.exe in x64dbg]

I thought that perhaps this is because notepad.exe is a system program and is tightly tied to the Windows system APIs, and some parts of it (and maybe all the code) are always loaded into RAM while Windows is running. Therefore, I tried to do the same with x64dbg itself, and saw about the same picture:

- image base: 0x140000000
- entry point (in headers): 0x2440
- entry point in VM: 0x7FF6B0E82440
- location of stack in VM: 0xFDA07F8000

So the questions are:

- Why are sections of some programs mapped to addresses greater than 0x7ff000000000, which doesn't match PE headers?
- How are these processes different from others?
- How does the OS decide where to place the stack in virtual memory?
- Each thread has its own stack. As you can see from the screenshots, thread stacks are usually placed before code sections. If the program starts a dynamic number of threads, this memory may not be enough. Where, in this case, will stacks be allocated for new threads?
- How can I programmatically, having an executable file, but not running it, statically determine at what addresses in the virtual memory of its process the sections, the stack will be located, and what address spaces will be available for allocation on the heap?

I understand that this can be difficult to explain in a nutshell, so I appreciate if, in addition to answering my questions, you can recommend me some reading material that will help me improve my understanding of the Windows virtual memory mapping.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is [Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), which is enabled by default in MSVC with the linker flag:
[`/DYNAMICBASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dynamicbase-use-address-space-layout-randomization?view=msvc-170).

To enable this, the flag `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE` (0x40) must be set in the PE header, at FileHeader -> OptionalHeader -> DllCharacteristics.

When enabled, the OS will select a random address for the base image, stack, and heap. The `ImageBase` specified in the PE header will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you. What about my third question about stack location? Does it always start at 0x8A000 with ASLR turned off?

Comment: @lem0nify yes, disabling ASLR will also making the heap and stack have a "static" address, as described in the Wikipedia page: *ASLR randomly arranges the address space positions of key data areas of a process, including the base of the executable and the positions of the stack, heap and libraries*

Comment: Where can I read information about these static addresses? I believe that some kind of address selection mechanism is still present there, because the program can run a dynamic number of threads, and each thread has its own stack. Given that in virtual memory, as seen from the screenshots, thread stacks are located before code sections, this memory may not be enough for all stacks. Where, in this case, will memory be allocated for them?

Comment: Good question, I've never actually thought about that, I haven't found any detailed paper about this on the internet so the best thing I can give you is [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1346381/13253010) to an answer that quoted *Mark Russinovich* in his book.